# Editing Pixel Art, Copyright and "The Ship of Theseus" Problem

Tags: sprites, copyright, art, pixel-art

*(Please read the entire question before you crucify me :p)*

This is a question that has been on my mind for some time.

Basically, How much of a sprite needs to be changed in order for you to claim "ownership" of said sprite. I've made a few examples to illustrate my point.

*(I made these examples specifically to illustrate my point)*

[image]

[I did not make this. I do not know who made this, I found it on Pinterest.](http://twitpic.com/4g8m87)

Focus on Far Left, Second to bottom. The Feather Hat Guy.

[image]

Would this be enough to call your own? (I would say probably not.)

...But what if your create unique animations?

[image][image]

What if I make it nearly unrecognizable...

[image]

...And give this unique animations.

[image][image]

What if the end product has nothing in common except the skin tone?

[image]

What if a design is so simplistic, it would actually be easier to draw it yourself? Would this even be considered editing at this point?

[image]

So, my two main questions are...

1. Can you Copyright an pixel art "Style"?
2. How much of a sprite needs to be changed in order for you to claim "ownership" of said sprite.

Comment: This looks like a question to ask a lawyer, not a game developer. If you have trouble with the making-a-game parts of making your game (like "how do I implement feature X? / fix bug Y?"), ask here. Folks with expertise in making game can help with that. If you're wondering whether your approach for making a game is legal, ask a lawyer.

Comment: Looks like you're talented enough to come up with your own stuff, why do you want to add more stress to your life by "maybe" infringing a copyright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the memorandum opinion from the US court case of [Dave Grossman Designs, Inc. v. Bortin](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/347/1150/1404364/):

> The law of copyright is clear that only specific expressions of an
> idea may be copyrighted, that other parties may copy that idea, but
> that other parties may not copy that specific expression of the idea
> or portions thereof. For example, Picasso may be entitled to a
> copyright on his portrait of three women painted in his Cubist motif.
> Any artist, however, may paint a picture of any subject in the Cubist
> motif, including a portrait of three women, and not violate Picasso's
> copyright so long as the second artist does not *substantially* copy
> Picasso's.

Based on that precedent, in the US you cannot copyright style per say and you can assert ownership of a specific expression (for instance a sprite) provided that it doesn't not substantially copy someone else's work. To my knowledge, there's no specific definition of what constitutes "substantially". [US copyright caselaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:United_States_copyright_case_law) is complex; such is the dominion of legal professionals.